# facebook photo tagging

Tags: php, facebook, tagging

how to show thumbnail view of tagged friends of user in a photo as the most applications like 'top-friends' are doing.I've used graph api but it only shows name of tagged friends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [photo.addTag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addTag)

Download link: http://pearhub.org/get/facebook-0.1.0.tgz

Also read this: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/371

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any package for this, just simple GD manipulations and merging the thumbnail pics on the original pic. You can collect the picture of the friends using their IDs:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[userID]/picture
```

Put the ID over there on the this url to get the pictures of the friends, now you can merge them using the PHP GD library functions like `imagecopymerge()`, check some tutorials and docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php). By doing the steps you can easily generate the images that you want to post on facebook and then just tag the friends and post it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com , If you found this answer useful, then don't forget to mark it as correct...